# volumes solving for dx or dy

Tags: calculus, volume

The only problem I have with this is knowing when you are solving for dx or dy. For example, this question which says

find the volume of the solid created by rotating the region bounded by y = 2x-4, y = 0, and x = 3, about the line x = 4. This one is dy. Instead of y = 2x-4, the person solved in respect to x and got y+4/(2).

And then there is this one, similar to the above but about the line y = -3. This one is dx. I don't understand why. Help appreciated.

Comment: If we are going to calculate volume by slicing, then you remember that when you are rotating about the $x$-axis, you integrate with respect to $x$. The same is true if you are rotating about any line *parallel* to the $x$-axis, like $y=17$. If you are rotating about the $y$-axis and calculating using slicing, you recall that one integrates with respect to $y$. The same is true for rotation about any line parallel to the $y$-axis, like $x=-6$.  But it is better to visualize the slices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Sometimes it is easier to use horizontal strips than vertical (or the other way around). It also depends on the method you choose to find the volume, there is washer(disk) or shells. Shells you want parallel strips to the axis of rotation. Washer(disk) you want perpendicular strips to the axis of rotation. $x=f(y)$ think horizontal strip. $y=g(x)$ think vertical strip. In your problem you have you want to rotate the region bounded by $y=2x-4$, $y=0$, and $x=3$ about $x=4$. So your figure can be represented by a bunch of vertical strips. And vertical strips are parallel to vertical lines, the vertical line we talking about is the axis of rotation here. So I would do shells method here. $V=\int_2^3 2 \cdot \pi (4-x)(2x-4)dx $. Now if you want to look at your figure in terms of horizontal strips solve for $x$ given $y=2x-4$. This will mean we will use the washer(disk) method though. $x=\frac{y+4}{2}$. So $V=\int_0^2 \pi ((4-\frac{y+4}{2})^2-(4-3)^2) dy$

Comment: very nice explanation(+1). are you a teacher?

Comment: Used to be and thanks. But just because I was a teacher doesn't mean I know all maths so I will not sit here and claim to be an expert. You guys on this math site are the real geniuses.  You guys impress me when you solve these crazy math problems I have never seen.

Comment: Also tried to show a picture of what was happening too if that helps.

Comment: sweet. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

If the piece of the function rotates around the $x$-axis, you use $dx$

If it rotates around the $y$-axis, you use the inverse function and calculate
the values of the function to get the limits of the integral.

Comment: but the problem above says its rotating about the line x = 4. Why use dy here?

Comment: The formula with $dx$ only works, if the function rotates around the $x$-axis. $x=4$ is parallel to the $y$-axis.